# IOS twitter feed tutorial

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am currently building an app where they require all their users to be able to view their feeds only.

I looked at a lot of tutorials online which talk about the new api v1.1 of twitter and now authentication is required at all times.

I see a lot of examples and even successfully followed several of them like

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/

I even saw a tutorial posted on the twitter dev page.Following all of these focused on a few key elements

- Using ACAccount to retrieve the account settings of the current user
- Using the SLRequest to encapsulate the HTTP request made to the twitter api
- Retrieving the data in JSON format, parsing it and presenting it to the user

Well my question is, I do not want user specific feeds. It's like a company updates their twitter regularly, users using the app should get feeds regarding the company. So I was wondering if there was a way, the app provides some default or hard coded authentication information ?

Is there some sort of tutorial, library or anything out there to help me move in the correct direction ?

Thank You for your time and help.

Comment: You just want to import the feed of a public twitter account?

Comment: Hello AJak, this is the twitter account https://twitter.com/MorleyGaelsGAA, I want to import these feeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your going to want to implement the following API call to get that information:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Once your application is authorized you can make a call to,

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/MorleyGaelsGAA.json

That should give you the information you're looking for.